# Why does this os slow to download?

Tags: download

I just bought the program. Since this is a very large download, I am surprised that the speed is 14.4 kb/sec which just barely crawls,  It even dropped at a lower speed than that; like 9 kb/sec,  At the speed, I am getting, it will take from 1 to 2 days before it is finished.  Never have I got such slow speeds as that on the internet.  Dial-up was faster than that. Depending upon a program, I have gotten speeds from approx. 150 kb/sec upwards to 3 Mb/sec.  If this os takes a lot of time to download, it is possible that it could hang up and unable to resume where I left off.  This has happened to me and I had to start all over again.  It would be worth it to me to purchase a ready-made os or flash drive.
By the time I get an answer, I hope this download is successful.  Also, where I live I am unable to get the fastest wi fi as I have to rely on satellite and with so much snow and ice here with extream low temperatures, sometimes the wi fi goes out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a torrent client to speed up the download. I think the low speed you are getting is caused by your ISP being so far away from the elementary servers. Using a torrent link from the magnet icon will probably increase the speed.

Answer (score 2):

Tried the download link and it works fine, at least on my location. Others near your area/can test connections over VPN can at least try to check if your mirror is experiencing problems.

Since you mentioned that you're using satellite and experiencing snow, that seems to be the most plausible reason why your downloads are so slow. For such connections, try using the magnet link instead of the direct link for a more consistent and reliable download.